# Add back button in checkout page of OpenCart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to add back button in checkout page to redirect to the cart page. Which file has to be modified?

Answer (score 2):

In your `catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php` file add the line below to `index() function` :

```
$data['back_to_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
```

In your `checkout.tpl` wherever you need the back button add this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo $back_to_cart ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
```

Comment: Hi Temkar, i place above lines of code in respective files .. but when i mouse over to the back button.. i seen error msg like Undefined variable: back_to_cart , How can i resolve it

Comment: you sure you placed them in the right files? where are you using $back_to_cart and where have you defined it

Comment: i just added that anchor tag line of code which u gave, added in this file catalog/view/theme/BurnEngine/template/checkout/checkout.tpl

i didn't defined any where.. pls help me where to define

Comment: catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php  add $data['back_to_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart'); in index() function

Comment: yes added above line of code in that file.. but shows undefined varibale: back_to_cart

after click on back button the URL is like this..

http://siteurl/%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20Undefined%20variable:%20back_to_cart%20in%20%3Cb%3E/home/venky/public_html/mfm3/catalog/view/theme/BurnEngine/template/checkout/checkout.tpl%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E35%3C/b%3E

Comment: where in the file did you add it

Comment: $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/checkout', $data));  before this line right?

Comment: if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/checkout.tpl')) {
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/checkout.tpl', $data));
  } else {
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/checkout/checkout.tpl', $data));
  }

after this if block i added the code which u gave.. in index function

Comment: Add it before the block

Comment: yes placed in before that block , even also not working. Getting same error msg like back_to_cart is undefined

Comment: I am not able to help in that case because this is how it is done

Comment: Directly i gave  href="index.php?route=checkout/cart"  in that anchor tag..bcoz am not able to get the solution ...

thank you Temkar, for u r support..